# ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

Tags: python

can anyone help me with the below error?

```
Error occurred ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

I am using requests==2.28.2 version, and while logging into tableau server using rest API the error is coming.

As I am first creating the session, and then doing the post request.

Can you help me to resolve the issue python?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The problem is on the side of the API that you are calling.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.